# How do I identify what to put inside the \usepackage{...} from the CTAN documentation?

Tags: packages, ctan

I often am confused about how to find the package name for use within the `\usepackage{...}` when looking at documentation. Where is this located?

Thanks

Comment: Usually, the package name is the first word in the title of the CTAN page, what does seem to be wrong, here? Can you link the CTAN webpage you're struggling with?

Comment: As others have said, _usually_ the CTAN package name matches the `.sty` file name.  There are several exceptions, so if that doesn't work, try looking at the documentation, or browse the TDS archive looking for `.sty` files, or look for examples online, or .  There is no one-rule-fits-all solution

Comment: \usepackage reads a single .sty file, even if there are several in one directory.  The autoload feature of MikTeX will work even if the folder name is different.  Downloading into admin or loading the documentation requires the correct folder name.

Comment: ... *normally* the documentation should have usage example...? Otherwise yes, search for ProvidePackage is an option but that's about as bad as reading the source code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Interesting question! First I thought that the question was silly but after thinking about it for some minutes, I changed my mind :).
- Here is a "brute force" approach that I usually use in cases where it is unclear.

---

1. Take https://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek, for example (thanks to Phelype Oleinik for the example).
   [image]
2. Here, we choose the `bmpsize` package (https://ctan.org/pkg/bmpsize). Then we open the **Package Documentation**.
   [image]
3. Now, you can search for *both*, `ProvidesPackage` and `usepackage`. I strongly recommend using Adobe Reader (or similar) since the search does not always work as expected when I use the built-in PDF viewer of my browser (Chrome).
   [image]

This should give you a good **starting point**.

Answer (score 0):

It will simply be the package name as listed on CTAN. For any options, these should be listed in the package documentation PDF file.

Comment: Not necessarily.  The CTAN package name may be different from the `.sty` file name.  A CTAN package may have several `.sty` in them (e.g., https://ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek), or it may have no `.sty` at all (e.g., https://ctan.org/pkg/garamond-math).

Comment: so should you find the .sty file?